# Is it possible to call store.dispatch synchronously in redux-saga?

Tags: redux, redux-saga

Is it possible to call store.dispatch synchronously in redux-saga, that is, return after the saga which takes its action finished running. For example, the following code

```
const { createStore, applyMiddleware } =require('redux')
const createSagaMiddleware =require('redux-saga').default
const { takeEvery ,take,fork,put}=require('redux-saga/effects') 
const {delay} =require('redux-saga')
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
const reducer=(state=[],action)=>{return [...state,action.type];}
const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
)
function* takeSaga() {
    const action=yield take('testTake')
    yield delay(1000);
    console.log('from takeSaga')
}
sagaMiddleware.run(takeSaga)
const main=async ()=>{
   store.dispatch({type: 'testTake'})
   console.log("from main");
}
main();
```

outputs

```
from main
from takeSaga
```

That is, the `store.dispatch({type: 'testTake'})` returns after `takeSaga` executed the `yield delay(1000)` statement. What I want to archive is that the `store.dispatch({type: 'testTake'})` returns only after the `takeSaga` has finished its last statement `console.log('from takeSaga')`, so that the expected output should be

```
from takeSaga
from main
```

Is that possible? I have tried `await store.dispatch({type: 'testTake'})` but without success.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, no, that's not possible.

`store.dispatch()` is, by itself, 100% synchronous.  When you call it, it runs your reducer, runs any subscription callbacks, and returns.

Middleware can change that, by intercepting actions and delaying them in some way.  But, if a middleware intercepts and delays an action, the original `dispatch()` call will still return, because this particular event loop needs to run to completion.

In your example, what happens is:

- The saga middleware sees the action, and calls `next(action)`, eventually reaching the real `store.dispatch`
- The store calls the root reducer
- The store calls all subscriber functions
- `store.dispatch` returns
- The call to `next(action)` returns, and the saga middleware continues executing
- The saga middleware begins running any sagas that need to know about this action
- Your saga begins to run, and yields a `delay()` effect, telling the middleware it wants to wait before it continues.  The `yield` statement pauses your saga.
- The middleware sees that no other sagas care about this action, and returns
- A second later, the timeout expires, and the middleware tries to resume running your saga

So, the `delay()` effect causes the middleware to finish up its current work and return.  You can't make the event loop block for a second with that.